# Use of Hibernate when constraints are not defined

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

We have a requirement to redesign one application but without doing any modification on the database.

The current code uses plain jdbc to query data. We are planning to implement hibernate instead as part of the redesign.

The problem is the current database doesn't have any constraints present at the database level.

For example if there are two entities Course and Review. The current database doesn't have any mapping between them.

Now in this case if I implement hibernate and try to have @OneToMany between Course and Review, without having those constraints in the database, will that work out fine?

Comment: What is stopping you from trying this?

Comment: It works. But I wanted to know the repercussions in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

1 To stop hibernate from changing you scheme set parameter

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

[81.2 Initialize a Database Using Hibernate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

2 Set GeneratedValue strategies to use existing sequences

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq", sequenceName="my_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
private Long id;
```

This way Hibernate will change nothing in your schema. It will not create any sequences, tables, foreign keys, constraints e.t.c. Just use existing structure and fall if something wrong with it )

Comment: If I don't keep constraint in db and maintain it only in the hibernate side. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: You already maintain constraints manually. Now hibernate will do a part of work for you. I suppose nothing will change.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no cascading from `Course` to `Review`s and you delete `Course` the delete will go through without any complaints. With constraint present, DB would have complained about existing child records(Review in this case).

So special care needs to be taken specifying the cascade.